# Is there a generalization of linear algebra that allows fractional ranks?

Tags: linear-algebra

The rank is the number of linearly independent rows/cols of a matrix.  Generally, we think of linear independence as a binary property.  But we could imagine an alternative definition that allows for numbers in the range [0,1].  Then, we could have fractional ranks.

I'm curious if there's any use to such generalizations of rank/independence, or if anyone has even thought about it before?

Comment: Dimensions of objects in monoidal categories can be arbitrary elements of the base ring, and sometimes this freedom is used: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/16668/does-any-tensor-category-correspond-to-a-bialgebra

Comment: Hello Mike -- You ask first for every number in [0,1] but then for fractional ranks.    Wikipedia let's a fractional part be real, but the word made me think of fractions.  Are you interested in situations in linear algebra where the generalized ranks are rational?

Comment: Sorry, the number between [0,1] would be an alternative definition for two rows being linearly independent.  Then the rank could take on any real range from [1:n], where n is the number of rows/col of the matrix.  That's just one idea I had about how ranks might be generalized.  You could potentially have others, e.g. by allowing fractionally many columns in the matrix, but I this seems to make even less sense intuitively.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

von Neumann thought about this; the keyword is [continuous geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_geometry).